Lambda function deployed in localstack with gateway not able to access secretsmanager service with connection refuesed
My localstack is up with the following file
version: "3.8"

networks:
  ms-local-net:
   name: ms-local-net

services:
  db:
    image: ms-local-db
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - ms-local-net
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME:-localstack-main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    networks: 
     - ms-local-net
     
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      # LocalStack configuration: https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/configuration/
      - DEBUG=1
      - HOST_LAMBDA_DIR=${PWD}
      - LAMBDA_LIMITS_CODE_SIZE_ZIPPED=231939905
      - LAMBDA_LIMITS_CREATE_FUNCTION_REQUEST_SIZE=231939905
      - LAMBDA_LIMITS_CODE_SIZE_UNZIPPED=371923968
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=1
      - LAMBDA_RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT_TIMEOUT=300
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="local"
      - AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
      - JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED'
      - SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT='aws-secretsmanager:/secrets/test-secret'
      - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack

    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

After this,
I created and deployed the lambda function using the following command
aws --profile localstack lambda create-function  --function-name api --runtime java17 --handler com.medisprout.StreamLambdaHandler --region us-east-1 --zip-file fileb://ms-api-1.12.0-lambda-package.zip  --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/Test-Role

And created the API gateway with the following commands -> https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/apigateway/
aws --profile localstack apigateway create-rest-api --region us-east-1
--name "ms-api"

aws --profile localstack apigateway create-resource --rest-api-id iw8c0cp1gi  --parent-id tshgz7guq4 --path-part "{somethingId}"

aws --profile localstack apigateway put-method --rest-api-id iw8c0cp1gi --resource-id np2fk6x461 --http-method GET
--request-parameters "method.request.path.somethingId=true" --authorization-type "NONE"

aws --profile localstack apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id iw8c0cp1gi --resource-id np2fk6x461 --http-method GET --type AWS_PROXY
--integration-http-method POST   --uri arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:api/invocations
--passthrough-behavior WHEN_NO_MATCH

aws --profile localstack apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id iw8c0cp1gi --stage-name test

But when I try to access it using the following,
curl -X GET http://localhost:4566/restapis/iw8c0cp1gi/test/user_request/test, I am getting
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:4566 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
Please help me what I am missing.
